# Maven jmeter plugin: SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have something like this in my jmx file of jmeter:

```
<stringProp name="SoapSampler.URL_DATA">http://192.168.0.1:8080/abc/Service</stringProp>
```

I'm using jmeter maven plugin to get the performance test result when doing the maven build. It's working perfectly.

Now I changed that to a user defined variable in jmeter and try to run that. I get the following error:

**"SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog"**

Changes in jmx file:

```
      <elementProp name="server" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">server</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">http://192.168.0.1:8080</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>


<stringProp name="SoapSampler.URL_DATA">${server}/abc/Service</stringProp>
```

However the modified changes works perfectly if executed directly from jmeter GUI. Fails only when executed during maven build.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.abc.def.performance</groupId>
<artifactId>abc-performance</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>



<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- An AntPath-Style pattern matching a JMeter XML result file to 
                            analyze. Must be a fully qualified path. File may be GZiped, must end in 
                            .gz then. Default: not set. Required. -->
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>
                        <!-- directory where to store analysis result files. Default: ${project.build.directory} 
                            Required. -->
                        <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/results</targetDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml

Comment: Can you create an empty file, copy your pom contents and save it again with UTF-8  encoding and try running it again.

Comment: @Balaji it doesn't make sense. we're not changing pom file. This error comes when we modify the jmx file to use userdefined variable.

Comment: But u did mention that it works fine when you normally run the jmeter and it fails only when you run thru pom. It looks like your pom has "bom - byte order marking". Thats why asked you to do the above. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

Comment: For the initial case without the userdefined variables, the same pom works. Issue comes only when we add userdefined variables in jmx.

Comment: Can you post the configuration file you changed and also the complete log trace ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75675/discussion-between-balaji-and-praveesh-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` and
Uncomment below lines from your jmeter.properties file (inside bin folder of jmeter installation folder):

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular error message is triggered by the xml parser when the results file is not in xml format. Likely the results file is in CSV format because `output_format` is not set to XML